# Recursively multiply all values in an array Python

Tags: python, recursion

I've had a look through the forums and can't find anything to do with multiplying all elements in an array recursively.

I've created the following code that almost does what I want. The goal is to use no loops and only recursion.

Here's the code:

```
def multAll(k,A):
    multAllAux(k,A)
    return A[:]

def multAllAux(k,A):
    B = [0]
    if A == []:
        return 0
    else:
        B[0] = (A[0] * k)
        B.append(multAllAux(k,A[1:]))

    return B

print(multAllAux(10, [5,12,31,7,25] ))
```

The current output is:

```
[50, [120, [310, [70, [250, 0]]]]]
```

However, it should be:

```
[50,120,310,70,250]
```

I know I am close, but I am at a complete loss at this point. The restrictions of no loops and solely recursion has left me boggled!

Comment: @usr2564301 I've just had a look and I can see there is "insert()" but as this requires a second attribute (for a specific index) I didn't feel it would work appropriately? I.e. sort of defeats the automation of the recursive format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
B.append(multAllAux(k,A[1:])))
```

What `.append(..)` does is it takes the argument, **considers it as a single element** and adds that element to the end of the list. What you want is to concatenate to the list (ie the item being added should be seen as a list of elements rather than one single element).

You can say something like: `B = B + multAllAux(..)` or just use `+=`

```
B += multAllAux(...)
```

---

BTW, if you wanted to multiply a single number to a list, there is a very similar construct: `map(..)`. Note that this behaves slightly differently depending on whether you're using Py2 or Py3.

```
print(map(lambda x: x * 10, [5,12,31,7,25]))
```

Comment: I've tried using your += method, however I'm now receiving `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: You should not `return 0`, but instead `return []`.

Comment: amazing! Both yours and @Rishav have provided useful and working answers, thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your `multAllAux` function returns a `list`. If you append a list to another list, you get this nested list kind of structure that you are getting right now.

If you instead use the "extend" function; it will work as expected.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.extend([4, 5])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`extend` takes the *elements* from a second list and adds them to the first list, instead of adding the second *list itself* which is what `append` does!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. After changing from the append() function to extend(), I'm now receiving `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: @YashMorar that's because your return-type is  not consistent. You return 0 if `A` is empty and a list otherwise. Return an empty list instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your function also returns a zero at the end of the list, which you don't need. You can try this:

```
def mult(k, A: list) -> list:
    return [k * A[0]] + mult(k, A[1:]) if A else []
```

Comment: Wow looks like something straight out of a Haskell book

Comment: @Rishav, yep, that's because I'm learning Haskell right now. One may say I temporarily have a Haskell accent :P